# Can't i play one sound with several buttons' click?

Tags: android, audio, button

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.cvp11 && v.getId()==R.id.cvp22 && v.getId()==R.id.cvp32)
        yc.start();
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.cvp12 && v.getId()==R.id.cvp21 && v.getId()==R.id.cvp31)
        dc.start();

}
```

Without adding or statements,it play the sound with cvp11 and cvp12 button clicks but i want also play these sound with other button clicks.However when i write like that,none of them plays when i click each button.What's wrong? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `&&` (logical AND operator) you meant to do `||` (logical OR operator):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.cvp11 || v.getId()==R.id.cvp22 || v.getId()==R.id.cvp32)
        yc.start();
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.cvp12 || v.getId()==R.id.cvp21 || v.getId()==R.id.cvp31)
        dc.start();
}
```

Of course, for formatting and usability, the `switch` answer by @dmytrodanylyk is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Omg! How did i do that? I stayed in front of the computer a lot today and now my brain is burning.Thx Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
switch(v.getId())
{
 case R.id.cvp11:
 case R.id.cvp22:
 case R.id.cvp32:
 yc.start();
 break;

 case R.id.cvp12:
 case R.id.cvp21:
 case R.id.cvp31:
 dc.start();
 break;

}
```

Comment: And that's much more practical way of it.Thank you,dmytrodanylyk.